# Studing rand( ) function

Tags: c++

I've tried analize some probabilities involving rand( ) function, so I done this code:

```
int vetor_aleatorio[2], vetor_aleatorio_2[2], contador_de_atribuicoes = 0;

srand(time(NULL));
do {
     contador_de_atribuicoes += 1;
     for (int i=0; i<1; i++) 
     {
        vetor_aleatorio[i] = rand() % 3 + 1;
        vetor_aleatorio_2[i] = rand() % 3 + 1;
     } 
   } while (vetor_aleatorio != vetor_aleatorio_2);

int c = contador_de_atribuicoes - 1;
std::cout << "A quantidade de atribuicoes para que o valor das duas arrays fossem iguais, foi: " << c << std::endl;
```

I done this to try analize how many assignments are necessary for vetor_aleatorio be equal to vetor_aleatorio_2... But, It is never finished, even I using small arrays and a short sample space on the rand( ), indicating that that arrays aren't equal.

Can someone explain me for what this happens ?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of your `for` loop?

Comment: the one good advice is to use english language for naming

Comment: You should start with a simpler program that allows you to explore how the basic language works. Don't dive right into the deep end.

Comment: fill up the entire vector

Comment: @Blender he's testing how well the compiler optimizes as well ;)

Comment: The for is to insert into array the aleatory values generated by rand( ).

Comment: @TheJoker: But the only value that `i` will have in the body of the `for` loop is `0`, so your arrays will have hold exactly one value. You could've just done `while (rand() % 3 != rand() % 3) { ++loops; }`

Comment: Itsn't the way I'd want, but works.

Comment: when you are filling up the vectors, compare the index to the size, not to one less. when comparing vectors, use the function provided in my answer

Answer (score 3):

In line

```
while (vetor_aleatorio != vetor_aleatorio_2)
```

you are comparing addresses of arrays (because name of the array is a pointer to the first entry), which are different.

```
while (vetor_aleatorio != vetor_aleatorio_2)
              ^                   ^
//          this is address       and this is address too
```

You can write:

```
do {
     contador_de_atribuicoes += 1;
     vetor_aleatorio[0] = rand() % 3 + 1;
     vetor_aleatorio_2[0] = rand() % 3 + 1;

} while ( vetor_aleatorio[0] != vetor_aleatorio[0]);
```

Comment: So, can you explain me how can I check if the values of the arrays are equals?

Comment: @TheJoker vetor_aleatorio[0] != vetor_aleatorio[0]

Comment: Thus, Cannot I compare the whole array once?

Comment: @TheJoker yes, you can, but your array has one entry only and each time you generate just two new values so why not to compare them directly?

Comment: Man, Firstly, It was a little example. I'd do arrays much longer.

Comment: @TheJoker you can call a function bool cmp() { //iterate over arrays, return true if (condition) }

Comment: If you use `std::vector` or `std::array` then `==` will work as you intended.  If you want to stick with an array, then you can either loop yourself or use e.g. [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) or even  `memcmp()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing whether the two arrays are the same incorrectly. What you are comparing is if the pointer to the start of the arrays are the same, which will never be true. You need to explicitly compare each of the elements in each array not the array variables themselves.

Comment: So, can you explain me how can I check if the values of the arrays are equals?

Comment: @TheJoker You could write a function that accepts two arrays and iterates through each of them returning false as soon as the value at the current index is different in one from the other, finally returning true indicating they are equal

Answer (score -1):

use for comparision: ( place before your `main` )

```
bool comp_vec_2( int* v1, int* v2 )
{
    for( int i=0; i<2; ++i )
        if( v1[i] != v2[i] )
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Notice that you should compare index less than 2, not 1.
Same goes when you are filling up the vector

replace while condition with

```
while ( ! comp_vec_2(vetor_aleatorio, vetor_aleatorio_2) ) ;
```

Comment: This doesn't really help the OP if you don't tell him where to use it.

Comment: You could also use a standard library algorithm instead of writing a one-off function: `std::equal(vetor_aleatorio, vetor_aleatorio + 2, vetor_aleatorio_2)`